# How can I stop the f1 key from opening the 'help' window in any program?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, function-keys

F1 Function Key Tries to open the 'help' window in any program, and if that program doesn't have a 'help' window/center, it causes the window's screen to flicker. This is very annoying in Notepad++ or in games that I play and use the key. I don't want to rebind the key because some of these games do not allow me to change the controls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the F1 "Help" key on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1102468/how-do-i-disable-the-f1-help-key-on-windows-10)

Comment: Try the software of the link, remap the key to see if it helps.https://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

Disable the F1 key on the Registry Editor:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Disables F1 key - Help and Support - in Windows 10
;Ramesh Srinivasan, Winhelponline.com

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win32]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win64]
@=""
```

[Source](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-f1-key-help-windows-10/)

[Duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1102468/how-do-i-disable-the-f1-help-key-on-windows-10)

Comment: I am using windows 7.I tried this. It doesn't work.

Comment: Restart your computer

Comment: I have three times